# Invalid email: "from@your_app_domain.com" in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Invalid email: "from@your_app_domain.com" in cakephp

I wrote this code in controller:

```
public function remember_password()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->request->data['User']['email']);
        if (empty($user)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This email does not exist in our database.', 'flash_fail');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
        }

        $hash = $this->User->generateHashChangePassword();

        $data = array(
            'User' => array(
                'id' => $user['User']['id'],
                'hash_change_password' => $hash
            )
        );

        $this->User->save($data);

        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->template('remember_password', 'default')
                ->config('gmail')
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->subject(__('Remember password - ' . Configure::read('Application.name')))
                ->to($user['User']['email'])
                ->from(Configure::read('Application.from_email'))
                ->viewVars(array('hash' => $hash))
                ->send();

        $this->Session->setFlash('Check your e-mail to continue the process of recovering password.', 'flash_success');

    }
}
```

getting the above mentioned error. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your configuration for from(Configure::read('Application.from_email'))

Mostly is located in app/Config/core.php or in any other config file

configuration will be something like:

```
$config['Application'] = array(
'from_email'=>'from@your_app_domain.com',
    .......... ................
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscores in a domain are not valid, change the `Application.from_email` in your configuration to something else.

Comment: @Ankit Usually it's a file in the `app/Config/` folder.